# http post to login in c#

Tags: c#, http-post

i'm very noob in c# programming.

I want implement an http post to login on a web server. the correct implemetation (test with advanced rest) is an http post to http://localhost:8080/pentaho/j_spring_security_check with "j_username=admin&j_password=password" payload and application encoded content type .
With advanced rest, the server responses 302 and redirects to Home (and this is the right way).

I tried to implement the same thing in c# with this code (copied from google) but the server responsens 500 ....

Here the code:

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void doRequest()
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/pentaho/j_spring_security_check");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "j_username=admin&j_password=password";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
                     // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doRequest();
    }
}
```

can someone help me?
many thanks in advance

edit: here the stack trace

```
System.dll!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()  Sconosciuto
```

> edoc_giocattolo2.dll!edoc_giocattolo2.WebForm1.doRequest() Riga 45  C#
>       edoc_giocattolo2.dll!edoc_giocattolo2.WebForm1.Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Riga 63 C#
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs e) Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)    Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)    Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, string eventArgument)   Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection postData)   Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()  Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(System.Web.HttpContext context)    Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)    Sconosciuto
>       App_Web_kky3vf3s.dll!ASP.webform1_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)   C#
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously)  Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error)   Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb)  Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context)    Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Sconosciuto
>       [Transizione da nativo a gestito]
>       [Transizione da gestito a nativo]
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Sconosciuto
>       System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Sconosciuto
>       [Transizione AppDomain]

edit: i added a cast (HttpWebRequest) and now i have not a 500 internal error.
But i can't see the post request in firebug and i'm not logged in the server :(

Comment: Can you paste the Stacktrace?

Comment: of course  [Codice esterno] 
> edoc_giocattolo2.dll!edoc_giocattolo2.WebForm1.doRequest() Riga 45 C#
  edoc_giocattolo2.dll!edoc_giocattolo2.WebForm1.Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Riga 63 C#
  [Codice esterno]

Comment: Add the full stack trace to the end of your question, not here!

Comment: oops , i'm sorry ! is it ok now?